# gradlew.bat assembleDebug not working

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I ran this from command line

```
gradlew.bat assembleDebug
```

And it is showing me

```
Downloading httpd://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
.........................................................................
.........................................................................
Unzipping C:\Users\akshay\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.14.1-all\4cj8p00t3e5ni9e8iofg8ghvk7\gradle-2.14.1-all.zip to C:\Users\akshay\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.14.1-all\4cj8p00t3e5ni9e8iofg8ghvk7
```

And it's stuck there. What could be the issue?

Comment: Run with `gradlew.bat assembleDebug --info --debug` to get more details.

Comment: @GueorguiObregon I tried that it is deleting the above directory and then again stuck. following is the output:Deleting directory C:\Users\akshay\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.14.1-all\4cj8p00t3e5ni9e8iofg8ghvk7\gradle-2.14.1
Unzipping C:\Users\amanathk\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.14.1-all\4cj8p00t3e5ni9e8iofg8ghvk7\gradle-2.14.1-all.zip to C:\Users\akshay\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.14.1-all\4cj8p00t3e5ni9e8iofg8ghvk7